# Dblclick listener firing only once in my code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, event-listener, jquery-events

I am new to Javascript and I developed following code which works only once.

```js
function display(arr) {
  $(".tbl tbody").empty();
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $(".tbl tbody").append('<tr class="tblrow" id = "'+i+'"> <td><input id="editInput" type="text"/>'+arr[i].Empid+'</td><td>'+arr[i].name+'</td><td>'
     +arr[i].pd+'</td><td>'+arr[i].unplannedleaves+'</td><td>'+arr[i].response_time+'</td><td class = "tt"><button class="delbtn" id ="btn'+i+'">Delete</button></td></tr>');

    $("td").css("text-align", "center");
    $("td").css("border", "1px solid black");
    $(".tt").css("border", "none");
    $(".tbl").css("border", "none");
    $(".delbtn").css("display", "none");
  }
}

$("tr").on('dblclick', function() {
  var s = this.id;
  $("#btn" + s).css("display", "block");
});

$(".delbtn").click(function() {
  var s = this.id;
  var k = s.slice(3);
  arr.splice(k, 1);
  display(arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addelem">
  <table class="tbl1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="empid" type="text" placeholder="EmpId">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="pd" type="number" placeholder="Pds Delivered">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="unp" type="number" placeholder="Unplanned leaves">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="rsp" type="number" placeholder="Response Time">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
  <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>

</div>
```

After my table gets displayed using`display` method. The first time I dblclick a row it works as expected and displays the delete button. I click delete the row gets deleted and the table is re-rendered. However, after this the row is no more dbl-clickable. I tried debugging but the control won't even go in the dblclick listener.

Can someone explain why is it so. Whats going wrong in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your tr element like this:

```
$(document).on('dblclick', "tr", function() {
  var s = this.id;
  $("#btn" + s).css("display", "block");
});
```

It will dynamically subscribe any new tr with your dblclick event

Comment: I tried this instead `$("tr").on('dblclick', function(){
      var s = this.id;
      $("#btn"+s).css("display","block");
     });`

Comment: Because in this way: `$("tr").on('dblclick', function(){ var s = this.id; $("#btn"+s).css("display","block"); });`, all the tr subscribe to your event when the page load, but the tr you will add dynamically after the page is loaded won't be binded to the dblclick event. Have a look to this page: http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data in the section "Direct and delegated events"